# Find probability of sequence being divisible by 2

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Let $\{\xi_n\}, {n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of identically distributed independent random variables, all supported by natural numbers. We know that $0 < P(\xi_n \text{is divisible by 2}) < 1$.
> Let $S_n=\xi_1+\ldots+\xi_n \cdot$ . Prove that $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} P\left(S_n\right. \text{is divisible by 2}) = \frac12$.

So I tried to express probability of one random variable being divisible by 2 using characteristic function and expressing it through difference between two series. That’s how I got to $P(\xi$ divisible by 2) = ($\phi(\pi)$ + 1) / 2, where $\phi(\pi)$ is a characteristic function of $\xi$.

But that’s it on how far i got, because I don’t really understand how to extrapolate this on sequence of random variables. I think I should use Law of Large Numbers to finish the prove, but I can’t get transition between this two parts

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow this guidelines to get help in this forum. Notice that there is a specific section called **Avoid "no clue" questions** which reads: *Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true (you may genuinely have no idea how to approach the problem), it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts.*

Comment: Hey, as an incentive, let me bribe you with the promise of a solution. I _believe_ I have a solution in mind, and will happily post it if you improve your post by editing in some efforts of your own in it too :)

Comment: What do you know about $\{\zeta_n\}$?  I gather that they are supported on the natural numbers, right?  Are they pairwise independent?

Comment: @lulu yes, they are pairwise independent

Comment: @lulu, yes, sorry, I fixed information in the post

Comment: @insipidintegrator I’ve edited the post, but that’s all i got for this :(

Comment: What is $\phi(\pi)$?

Comment: If you assume existence then:  letting $L$ be the limit, with have $L=L(1-2p)+p\implies L=\frac 12$.  For existence, see [Lyapunov Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Lyapunov_CLT).  Note:  Since you only care about parity, I replaced your $\zeta_n$ with $X_n$ where the $X_n$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli variables with probabiliy of getting $1$ equal to $p$.

Comment: @insipidintegrator a characteristic function of \xi
I used it to express probability of random variable being divisible by 2

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/718059/sum-of-independent-bernoulli-variables-with-parameter-p-which-is-also-a-random-v) is a related question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P(\xi_n \text{is divisible by 2}) = p$, such that $0<p<1$. Now we have two cases:

## Suppose $n$ is even.

We'll take all the $\xi_i$'s modulo $2$, i.e. define a set of random variables $\{X_i\}_{i\in\mathbb N}$ such that $$X_i = \begin{cases}
0 & \xi_i\ \text{is even}\\
1 & \xi_i\ \text{is odd}
\end{cases}$$
Then, the distribution for the discrete random variable $X_i$ is $$P(x_i) = \begin{cases}
p & ,x_i = 0\\
1-p & ,x_i  =1
\end{cases}$$
or more concisely, $X_i = \xi_i\mod 2$.

Now, the collection $\{X_i\}_{i\in\mathbb N}$ is an example of a one-dimensional [random walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk#One-dimensional_random_walk). Then, the probability for $A_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ to be even is $$P(A_n \ \text{is even}) =P\left(\bigcup_{i=0}^{n/2}\{A_n = 2i\}\right)= \sum_{i = 0}^{n/2}P(A_n = 2i)$$ because all the events are disjoint. The calculations take us to $$ = \sum_{i = 0}^{n/2}\binom{n}{2i}p^{n-2i}(1-p)^{2i}$$$$ = \frac12\left((p+1-p)^n + (2p-1)^ n\right) = \frac12\left(1 + (2p-1)^n\right)$$ (Whether is is $1-2p\ $ or $2p-1$ does not matter as $n$ is even; to see how I got the last line from the  penultimate line, refer to [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2528974/sum-of-odd-terms-of-a-binomial-expansion-sum-limits-k-text-odd-n-choose)) and thus we get $$\lim_{n\to\infty} P(A_n \ \text{is even})=\fbox{$\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}$} $$ as $|2p-1|<1$. To complete the problem, note that $S_n$ being even is exactly the same event as $A_n$ being even, so the probabilities must be equal.

**TL;DR**: $X_i$'s are $\operatorname {Bernoulli}(p)$ so $A_n\sim \operatorname{Bin}(n, p)$.

## Suppose $n$ is odd.

Can you do this by yourself now, using similar logic?

Answer (score 1):

I'll post an additional answer using slightly different methods, with hopes that it may be of interest to a future reader.

Take the same notation for probability of $\xi_n$'s: $$P(\xi_n \text{is divisible by 2}) = p,$$and the same definition of $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ as the previously posted answer.

For the collection of random variables $\{S_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$, define another set of random variables $\{T_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$, defined by $T_i = S_i\mod 2$. Then, we can write $$S_n = S_{n-1} + \xi_n$$ and hence $$T_n = \left(T_{n-1} + X_n\right)\mod 2.$$ This makes the set $\{T_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ a Discrete-Time Markov Chain, with the following (hopefully self-evident) probabilities:$$P(T_n = 1\bigg|T_{n-1} = 1) = P(X_n = 0) = p,$$$$P(T_n = 1\bigg|T_{n-1} = 0) = P(X_n = 1) = 1-p,$$$$P(T_n = 0\bigg|T_{n-1} = 1) = P(X_n = 1) = 1-p,$$and $$P(T_n = 0\bigg|T_{n-1} = 0) = P(X_n = 0) = p.$$
Thus the one-step probability transition matrix of $\{T_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$, indexed starting from $0$, is
$$\textbf{P} = \begin{bmatrix}p & 1-p\\1-p & p\end{bmatrix}.$$
The distribution of the initial random variable, $T_1$, is $$P_1 = [P(T_1 = 0)\quad P(T_1=1)]=\begin{pmatrix}p& 1-p\end{pmatrix}$$ and hence, the distribution of the random variable $T_n$, is $$P_n = [P(T_n = 0)\quad P(T_n=1)]=P_1\textbf{P}^{n-1}$$ which is equal to $$\dfrac12\begin{pmatrix}p& 1-p\end{pmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}(2p-1)^{n-1}+1 &1-(2p-1)^{n-1}\\ 1-(2p-1)^{n-1} & (2p-1)^{n-1}+1\end{bmatrix}$$ such that we get $$P(T_n = 0) = \dfrac{p\cdot\left((2p-1)^{n-1}+1\right) + (1-p)\cdot\left(1-(2p-1)^{n-1}\right)}{2}$$ and thus, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}P(T_n=0) = \frac12.$$

Comment: It's not really relevant, I was thinking along the wrong lines.